# JavaScript parallax effect is laggy

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax, lag

I use this js code to gain a parallax effect

```
(function() {
    var parallax = document.querySelectorAll(".parallax"),
    speed = 0.5;
    window.onscroll = function(){
        [].slice.call(parallax).forEach(function(el, i){
            var windowYOffset = window.pageYOffset,
            elBackgrounPos = "50% " + (windowYOffset * speed) + "px";
            el.style.backgroundPosition = elBackgrounPos;
        });
    };
})();
```

On Chrome browser it's nice and smooth but on IE and mobile browsers the background doesn't move smoothly, it's somehow laggy.
any solutions?

Comment: The laggy-ness is due to the memory and processing power required to move a large background image. IE and mobile browsers have restricted performance and so you will see problems like this unless you can reduce the image size.

Comment: Thanks Rory for quick answer. I tried a 50kb background with "repeat-y" css and a 2kb background with "repeat" css style and both of them are laggy. Really it's not possible to reduce a 2kb background size.

Comment: Try to move the background using transitions instead of background position.

Comment: and with and effect called translate3d you can move it with the gpu.